# Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type '[_]'

Tags: swift

Every time I try to compile this, I get the error:

```
Cannot convert value of type '[T]' to expected argument type '[_]'
```

I'm not really sure why this keeps happening, and I've tried to look up solutions but have found nothing that seemed helpful.
Here's my code:

```
class FetchRequest <T: NSManagedObject>: NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult> {
        init(entity: NSEntityDescription) {
        super.init()
        self.entity = entity
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    typealias FetchResult = (success: Bool, objects: [T], error: NSError?)
    func fetch <T> (request: FetchRequest<T>,
                     context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> FetchResult {
        do {
         let results = try context.fetch(request)
            return FetchResult(true, results as! [T], nil)
        } catch let error as NSError {
         return (false, [], error)
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I get the error on this line:

```
return FetchResult(true, results as! [T], nil)
```

Comment: Please give more information: where do you get the error? Can you reduce your code to a minimal example which shows the error?

Comment: Done, I added an edit to indicate where the error occurs in the file. Sorry about that.

Comment: Why does your `fetch` *instance* method take a `request:` parameter? Why not use `self`?

Comment: You know, I'm not entirely certain. I was following the example under Fetch Requests here: https://realm.io/news/jesse-squires-core-data-swift/ And it wasn't working so well for me.

Comment: @Nick Huh, I'm a bit confused as well. They've defined the `fetch` function and the `FetchResult` type-alias at the top-level of the file, but they're trying to use `T` in the type-alias, which doesn't make much sense as `T` isn't defined at that scope.

Comment: Yeah, I've decided to scrap the idea, as I just upgraded to Xcode 8 and Swift 3 today, so the changes and how it all works seems more convenient than what was provided there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have two generic placeholder types called `T`. One at class scope, one at method scope. When you say `results as! [T]`, you're referring to the `T` at *method* scope – which is unrelated to the class scope `T` used in your `FetchResult` type-alias, which is return type of your `fetch` method.

Therefore you simply need to rename one of your placeholders, or better yet, eliminate the seemingly redundant `request:` parameter from the method and just use `self` instead:

```
func fetch(inContext context: NSManagedObjectContext) -> FetchResult {
    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(self)
        return (true, results as! [T], nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        return (false, [], error)
    }
}
```

Now you can just simply call `fetch(inContext:)` on the `FetchRequest` instance that you want to fetch.